# tikz: How to place an arrow with label exactly in the middle of a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

In the following example, the label is in the middle of the line. But the arrow, which acts as a marker, is not in the middle. Only its head but not the center of the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    middlearrow/.style 2 args={
        decoration={             
            markings, 
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{triangle 45}, \node[#1] {#2};}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
]
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+}]        (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example: Label in the middle. But arrow isn't.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noticed, the `markings` mechanism puts the arrow in the selected `position` taking as reference its arrowhead. The following example demonstrates it clearly:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    middlearrow/.style 2 args={
        decoration={             
            markings, 
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{triangle 45}, \node[#1] {#2};}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    },
    my mark/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with{\color{red}\pgfuseplotmark{x}},
        },
        postaction=decorate,
    }
]
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+},my mark]        (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+},my mark]        (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+},my mark]        (0,-2) -- (4,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What to do then? Steven showed one possibility. The same approach can be taken, easily, using only TikZ options, specifically `xshift`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    middlearrow/.style 2 args={
        decoration={             
            markings, 
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[xshift=3.333pt]{triangle 45}, \node[#1] {#2};}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    },
]
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+}]        (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+}]        (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[middlearrow={below}{+}]        (0,-2) -- (4,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The "magic number" seems to be correct. To be really precise, one should go in `pgflibraryarrows.code.tex` file and compute the exact width of `triangle 45` arrow.

This solution does not prevent errors while changing line width.

Comment: Thanks. It works with this "magic number".
I'm wondering, if it could be "calculated" or "found out" automatically from the file `pgflibraryarrows.code.tex` you mentioned in such a way that also other arrow styles can be used. (Like: center_point_of_arrow_head = (arrow_head_right - arrow_head_left)/2. And then calculating new xshift value.)

Comment: @leacbern: you're welcome :) Telling truth, I don't think you can have _one for all_ `xshift`; perhaps with the new `arrows.meta` library things are different. You can always post a new question for such a problem: here we have some `tikz-arrows` experts :)

Answer (score 2):

Both the arrow and the plus sign were shifted `\makebox`es, and seem to work over various length spans.  I'm guessing, however, that the actual size of the makeboxes will depend on the size of the arrow head.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    middlearrow/.style 2 args={
        decoration={             
            markings, 
            mark=at position 0.5 with {%
  \makebox[4pt][r]{\arrow{triangle 45}}, \node[#1] {#2};}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
]
\draw[middlearrow={below}{\makebox[1pt][r]{+}}]        (0,0) -- (1,0);

\draw[middlearrow={below}{\makebox[1pt][r]{+}}]        (0,-.5) -- (2,-.5);

\draw[middlearrow={below}{\makebox[1pt][r]{+}}]        (0,-1) -- (3,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the hint with the \makebox command.
But unfortunately you have to change the position value for different line lengths.

Comment: @leacbern Please see revision.