# TikZ: Unexpected difference between \draw and -- vs \path and edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

While modifying [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175402/tikz-how-to-place-an-arrow-with-label-exactly-in-the-middle-of-a-line) for my own use, I encountered something unexpected.  In my experience, using `\draw (1) -- (2)` is equivalent to `\path (1) edge (2)`.  However, adding the option to `draw` or `edge` suggested in the linked answer gives different outcomes:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
 ->-/.style={
  decoration={
   markings,
   mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[xshift=1.4pt]{angle 90}, \node[below] {+};}
  },
  postaction={decorate}
 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (1) {};
 \node (2) [right of=1] {};
 \draw[->-] (1) -- (2);

 \node (3) [below of=1] {};
 \node (4) [right of=3] {};
 \path (3) edge[->-] (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Question

What is the reason for this different behavior?

Comment: I get the same output in each case here. In general, though, aren't `edges` supposed to be different in that they are constructed after the main path rather than as part of it?

Comment: Which answer is that? And I also don't get any difference. Must be some global option interfering. And edges are `to` paths not lines.

Comment: @percusse Oh, yes, sorry.  Added the missing link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not reproducible with a current TeX distribution.

Comment: @Paul What is your definition of "a current TeX distribution"?

Comment: @TysonWilliams: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)

Comment: @Werner I don't want to update my TeX distribution. I want to know what Paul means by "a current TeX distribution".

Comment: @TysonWilliams, at the present time, [TeX Live 2014](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), [MikTeX 2.9](http://miktex.org/download), or [MacTeX-2014](https://tug.org/mactex/) with all packages updated using the chosen distribution's package manager.