# Draw a simple figure with arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, node-connections

I have been trying to get this figure:

[image]

Can you offer me some guidance as to how to correct my code and also get the arrow heads in the center of the lines?  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex] (0,0) node{$(x_{0},y_{0})$} -- (45:3) node {$K^{-}_{k+1}$};
\draw[draw=blue!30,dashed,-latex] (0,0) -- (0:2);
\draw[draw=blue!30,dashed,latex-] (2,0) node {$K_{k+1}$} -- (2,2) ;
\draw[draw=blue!30,dashed,-latex] (2,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex] (2,0) node{$(x_{0},y_{0})$} -- (45:4) node {$K^{-}_{k+2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use a decoration as in e.g. [tikz: How to place an arrow with label exactly in the middle of a line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175402) Edit: or [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

By ussing `decorations.markings` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = latex,
     decoration = {markings,mark=at position .75 
                            with {\arrow[very thick]{latex}}},
    arrow/.style = {draw=blue!30,thick},
dasharrow/.style = {arrow,densely dashed}
                    ]
\draw[arrow,postaction={decorate}]        
                    (0,0) node[below]{$(x_{0},y_{0})$}
                          -- (45:3) node[above] {$K^{-}_{k+1}$};
\draw[dasharrow,->] (0,0) -- (2,0)  node[below] {$K_{k+1}$};
\draw[dasharrow,postaction={decorate}] (45:3) -- (2,0);
\draw[dasharrow,->] (2,0) -- (4,0)     node[below] {$K_{k+2}$};
\draw[arrow,postaction={decorate}]        
                    (2,0) -- ++ (45:3) node[above] {$K^{-}_{k+2}$};
\draw[dasharrow,postaction={decorate}] 
                    (2,0) + (45:3) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

Note: the angle between horizontal and vertical lines are not 90 degrees. If you like to have it, you need to redefined coordinates for horizontal arrows.

**Edit:** ups, in rush I didn't upload last image neither MWE code ... now is corrected.

Comment: @Joe, you are welcome. Happy TeXing!